# Component interaction in Angular2

Tags: angular, web-component

This is my problem, I have app component, header component and home component.
in app component template I am using `<header></header>` to make the header component.

Now in the home component, I want to access and call a method of header component.

If I use injection to grab Header component, the injector will create a new instance (it seems components are not a singleton).

How can I get that specific header component already created?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your header component to only ever be a singleton component you'll have to add it to your bootstrap.  I am not entirely sure if this is what you are asking though.  It sounds like you want to use a service instead of a component.

What I would do is make a service that you would then call in your component.  A service you can think of as a class with a bunch of function calls(services) within them.  Then you would require them into each component, something like:

```
import {My_Global_Service} from './global_services/MyService'

@Component{....} 
export class Header{

   constructor(private _my_global_service: My_Global_Service){}

}
```

Then you would bootstrap your `My_Global_Service` so it would be a 'singleton' instance throughout your application.

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {My_Global_Service} from './global_services/MyService'

bootstrap(MyApp, [
      My_Global_Service
])
```

Then you could just call this same service from your home component:

```
import {My_Global_Service} from './global_services/MyService'

@Component{....} 
export class Home{

   constructor(private _my_global_service: My_Global_Service){}

}
```

This will hold all of the same variables/functions in both the header and the home component.